# Is it correct to use ‘As part of' in this way?

Tags: grammar

> **As part of** his academic activities, he conducted research focused on
>   the design, implementation and operation of novel algorithms using
>   artificial intelligence. Within the framework of his research he
>   developed two solutions and presented result in his two scientific
>   publications.

Is it correct to use ‘As part of' in this way?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Before giving a longer answer, I'm curious if there's a reason this looks wrong to you?

Comment: this way....? which way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I personally would say "As a part of" because it has a better flow, but "As part of" works fine.